# Custom ordering in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

How do you define a specific ordering in Django `QuerySet`s?

Specifically, if I have a `QuerySet` like so: `['a10', 'a1', 'a2']`.

Regular order (using `Whatever.objects.order_by('someField')`) will give me `['a1', 'a10', 'a2']`, while I am looking for: `['a1', 'a2', 'a10']`.

What is the proper way to define my own ordering technique?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to specify database-side ordering in this way as it would be too backend-specific. You may wish to resort to good old-fashioned Python sorting:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

Foo.objects.create(name='a10')
Foo.objects.create(name='a1')
Foo.objects.create(name='a2')

ordered = sorted(Foo.objects.all(), key=lambda n: (n[0], int(n[1:])))
print ordered # yields a1, a2, 10
```

If you find yourself needing this kind of sorting a lot, I'd recommend making a custom `models.Manager` subclass for your model that performs the ordering. Something like:

```
class FooManager(models.Manager):
    def in_a_number_order(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = self.get_query_set().filter(*args, **kwargs)
        return sorted(qs, key=lambda n: (n[0], int(n[1:])))

class Foo(models.Model):
    ... as before ...
    objects = FooManager()

print Foo.objects.in_a_number_order()
print Foo.objects.in_a_number_order(id__in=[5, 4, 3]) # or any filtering expression
```

Comment: I get this error when trying this method: :   

'Model' object is unindexable

Comment: Does `sorted` return a queryset? Given that it's passed a queryset, I would think so, but I'm thinking it might also be converted to a list or something internally for sorting, then *that* gets returned.

Comment: I'm afraid `sorted` does not return a queryset; it is a built-in python function, so it doesn't know anything about Django. Django's querysets implement python's interface for iterables, so `sorted` is able to work on them because it thinks it has just been passed a list.  If you need to return a QS, AFAIK there's no easy way to create a QS off the list that sorted returns... it IS possible to fake a QS (basically implement its interface), but that can be tricky.  There are many Manager methods that don't return a QS, and this sorting function would be consistent with those, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 40):

@Jarret's answer (do the sort in Python) works great for simple cases.  As soon as you have a large table and want to, say, pull only the first page of results sorted in a certain way, this approach breaks (you have to pull every single row from the database before you can do the sort).  At that point I would look into adding a denormalized "sort" field which you populate from the "name" field at save-time, that you can sort on at the DB-level in the usual way.

Comment: +1 for addressing the performance-related issues; in fact, your suggestion is one we've used on some of our data that is used for reports, in a DB-agnostic environment, and we've got tens-of-millions of rows, so I can vouch that it works well.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you want to use it.

If you want to use it in your own templates, I would suggest to write a template-tag, that will do the ordering for you
In it, you could use any sorting algorithm you want to use.

In admin I do custom sorting by extending the templates to my needs and loading a template-tag as described above

Answer (score 0):

If you have larger data sets and additionally use a SOLR backend (e.g. with Haystack):

Use `solr.ICUCollationField` with the `numeric=true` option as type for the sort fields. This will sort according to language and if numbers are present will sort the number part according to numeric rules instead of string sorting.

See:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Language+Analysis#LanguageAnalysis-UnicodeCollation
http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/solr/schema/ICUCollationField.html