# How to get an auto-incrementing sort order in a Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I wrote this:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    ...
    sort_order = models.IntegerField(help_text="Leave negative to place at end", default=-1)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Set the sort order (if unset) to larger than the largest value"""
        if self.sort_order <= 0:
            largest = Department.objects.all().aggregate(x = models.Max('sort_order'))['x'] or 0
            self.sort_order = largest + 10
        super(Department, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

but I'm not proud of it.  Is there a better way to do this?  I could possibly roll this into a field, but not sure how I'd get back to the model table if I refactored the code there.  I can't use the autoincrement column because as FK values, those can't be changed.

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883575/custom-ordering-in-django It could help you

Comment: @Carl Meyer's answer on that one points to this kind of field, just doesn't elaborate on a better way to come up with the sort_order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that PositionField from [Django Positions](https://github.com/jpwatts/django-positions) does this and is currently in use with [Django CrowdSourcing](https://code.google.com/p/django-crowdsourcing/).  It's not exactly what I asked for, but appears that it might be a good, usable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm being obtuse, but doesn't django's built in [AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#autofield) do what you're looking for.

I know you don't want to mess with the primary key, but you could create another `AutoField`.

```
sort_field = models.AutoField()
```

Maybe you could look at overriding the AutoField to do what you want.

Comment: Per the code: "A model can't have more than one AutoField."  So, if you have an id field, you can't have a sort_order field.  I suppose you could let the sort_order be the primary key, but that would cause all sorts of strange behaviors if you were deleting by an ID that could change.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I should have checked up on it before posting my answer. I found more info about the implementation of multiple Auto fields here - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8576