# Sort by complex condition

Tags: python, django

```
Model1(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


Model2(models.Model):
  model1 = models.ManyToManyField(FontClass) 

res = Model1.objects.all().filter(....).order_by('model1__name....???')
```

How can sort the result by more complex condition such whether or not `model1__name` has an underscore in its name? For example, `Model1.objects.all().filter(....)` returns the following names:

```
aaa_bbb
aaaccc
aaa_ttt
aaa_ddd
ggggg
yyy_cccc
zzz_kkk
dddd
```

After sorting it should be:

```
aaa_bbb
zzz_kkk
aaa_ddd
aaa_ttt
yyy_cccc

aaaccc
ggggg
dddd
```

First the ones with the underscore in their names, then - without it.

Note that condition is just an example for I want to be to sort by even complex ones, I just want to get how to do that.

Comment: You could split the results into two lists, and then alphabetically sort them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom ordering in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883575/custom-ordering-in-django)

Comment: `Queryset.order_by()` relies on database ordering, IOW it just adds a SQL `order by` clause. So you can either try to setup your database to get the desired ordering or (if your typical dataset isn't too huge) go for a pure python sort but that might be way less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

How about just changing the compare function of a regular sort algorithm?

```
def comp(a, b):
    if a>b:
        return True

def mergeSort(alist):
    if len(alist)>1:
        mid = len(alist)//2
        lefthalf = alist[:mid]
        righthalf = alist[mid:]

        mergeSort(lefthalf)
        mergeSort(righthalf)

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i<len(lefthalf) and j<len(righthalf):
            if comp(righthalf[j], lefthalf[i]):
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                alist[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i<len(lefthalf):
            alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j<len(righthalf):
            alist[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1

my_list = [10,4,2,5,1]
mergeSort(my_list)
print my_list
```

Just change the "comp" function to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `extra` method of the `queryset` to apply database sorting

```
Model1.objects.extra(
    select={'has_underscore': "position('_' in name) > 0"}, 
    order_by=['-has_underscore'])
```

Note that, you will be tied to a specific database. My example is working on postgresql.