# Get records from a Django database using a list of IDs in a specific order

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to create a Django queryset that returns records in a specific order that matches a list of IDs.

My list of IDs is:

```
[34,12,4,89,3,67,11]
```

If I run the following query:

```
queryset = Item.objects.filter(pk__in=[34,12,4,89,3,67,11])
```

The query returns records in the ID order:

```
3,4,11,12,34,67,89
```

Is there any way to make the query return the records in the same order as the list?

If not is there a way to re-order the query result into the required order?

Comment: Is the ordering you've determined (34, 12, 4, ...) related to an attribute on the model at all?

Comment: Here's a potentially related question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883575/custom-ordering-in-django, though I don't think what you're looking for is possible without casting the queryset into an object like a list, then manually sorting that, for example with a custom lambda.

Comment: No the id list is not related to the model.

Comment: Without knowing more about your use case, another consideration might be to add this custom order as a (unique) int field on the model.  One advantage of this is separating the data from your code (so that it could be changed in the Django ORM, for instance).

Comment: How would one add a custom order as a unique field? How would that work?

Comment: I'm going to add this an answer instead because comments don't support code blocks.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: Adding this as an answer because OP asked about the approach in the comments of the original question.  Showing the snippets in comments didn't allow fenced code blocks.*

In the comments on the original question, I mentioned an alternative solution storing your order numbers in a model field, so that ordered queries would be simpler.

One use case for this is if you have a queue of objects where each item is a movie and the user is deciding which order to watch them.  You might want to let a Django admin or a user re-order the items (hence making it a field).  For the sake of a simple example let's assume there is only one user so we'll build the ordering into the model, as opposed to making a custom table to join through Item and User models.

The model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    # ...
    my_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
```

Set the attribute either at creation or later:

```
Item.objects.create(id=34, my_order=1)
Item.objects.create(id=12, my_order=2)
Item.objects.create(id=4, my_order=3)
# ...
```

Of course, you could create them and set `my_order` in any order you wished, and the result will still be the same.

Retrieve the objects in desired order:

```
queryset = Item.objects.order_by('my_order')
```

Comment: That solution would be ok if I wanted to return items in a pre specified order but my lists of IDs will change every time a search is done.