# Is there a way to use order_by in Django to specify the order in which the results are returned?

Tags: python, django, django-views

So far I have seen only ascending and descending uses for order_by.  I want to order_by(Risk) but have the results returned in High, Med, Low order (These are my options in the field), not based on alphabet sorting, the way order_by is done by default.

To explain it a different way...I have a Field in my model called "Risk".  Risk only  has 3 values across all the records, High,Med,Low.  When I run queries on the database I want it to sort the results of the query based on the the field Risk in the order of High,Med,Low, not the random order it is returning the records now.

**current code looks like this:**

```
    items = ScanData.objects.filter(Q(Owner__icontains="HooliCorp")).order_by(Risk)
```

Comment: It is not clear to me *what* you aim to do. Can you share the relevant models and use sample input/output to make clear what you aim to do?

Comment: Saving High/Med/Low seems inefficient, save these values as integers which is then easy to sorty by, and map the High/Med/Low to the integers via `choices` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#choices

Comment: Does it answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883575/custom-ordering-in-django

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko - i am dealing with thousands of records and the .csv files that I upload to the database output the risk field with the string High/Med/Low format.  I'm trying to avoid changing it to a number based system.

Comment: @errMSG if you are dealing with "thousands of records", the issue you should be worried about isnt transforming the data when performing one-time DB INSERT, but the performance you'll be having when doing non-optimal queries on every SELECT. Good luck though.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to annotate your query with some conditional statement that will output a number depending on the field value:

```
items = ScanData.objects.filter(
    Q(Owner__icontains="HooliCorp")
).annotate(
    risk_order=models.Case(
        models.When(Risk='Low', then=1),
        models.When(Risk='Med', then=2),
        models.When(Risk='High', then=3),
        output_field=models.IntegerField(),
    ),
).order_by('risk_order')
```

This will create an annotation on the results list with a number from 1 to 3, depending on the risk value and then it will order the query by this annotation.